# 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute '_cmysql'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I have this snippet of code:

```
from mysql.connector import connect
db = connect(host=host, user=user, password=pass, database=dbname)
db._cmysql.escape_string('string to be escaped')
```

I also have installed this package `pip install mysql-connector-python`.
When i run the above code in python3.9.1 I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\....\mysqlconnector.py", line 19, in <module>
    db._cmysql.escape_string('string to be escaped')
AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute '_cmysql'
```

what's wrong?

Comment: That snippet if for an other MySQL connector. (And in general avoid using underscore attributes. They should be used privately only.) What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @KlausD. I want to test a bug on _cmysql.escape_string method. Can you tell me which connector i need to intall?

Comment: Might be the deprecated `mysql-connector` or an older version of `mysql-connector-pyhton`. But actually you are having an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/781394).